# Expanding a div from the center while using hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsbin.com/mobapalo/1/edit

(not sure why the JS isn't working on sites p=review)

When I hover over a circle it will expand it by 50px in both height and width.

Although by doing this the center of the circle will move so in order to resolve this I originally moved the circle up and to the left by 25px and then when the mouse leaves I will colapse it down to the orignal size and move everything back to the original position.

the problem is if you keep everything as default the animation queue of course makes a queue so if you move the mouse fast over everything you get a large queue of items and it takes a while for it to catch up.

So i tried using removing the queue but now if i move the mouse fast it doesn't seem to execute some parts of the code and hence the circles move without being repositioned to their original position.

I have a 2nd problem if you make the window smaller all the circles start to overlap, is there anyway to keep the circles the same size and if you make the window smaller without making them overlap?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Just adding a CSS transition  for the width on hover would seem to be adequate. Overlap is probably because of positioning. Try re-thinking that.

Comment: I updated the question and I know why the overlap is happening I just cant figure out a way to fix it.

Comment: Create a **fixed width** div to contain the circles and add `position:relative` to that.